# Get array of bytes from Data object

Tags: swift

How do I get an array of bytes from a Data object? I want to get a subset of the data, for example from 0 to 128.

```
    func fileTransfer(fileData: Data?) {
    
        var byteCount: Int = 128
        var startByte: Int = 0
        
        // I want to get a subset of the fileData from startByte of size byteCount
        connectedPeripheral.writeValue(?????, for: fileBlockCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
    
    }
```

I'm new at this. Sorry if this is a simple question. I looked through [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data) and wasn't sure which function would be appropriate.

Comment: Your title and first sentence say "array of bytes," but your sample code that calls `writeValue` expects a Data. Which one do you want?

Comment: You're right. It expects Data. I need it to be received as an array of bytes. When I did this with a string it looked like this:
        `let data: String = "1"
        let valueString = (data as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this last comment. You may want to create a new question if you're having trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this case, where you want to start at the beginning of the data, you'd use `prefix`:

```
let data: Data = ...
let toWrite = data.prefix(128)
```

This will return **up to** 128 bytes from the beginning. If `data` is shorter than that, then it will truncate without crashing. But you may need to check the length if that's important. Note that `prefix` is O(1) here. It does not require a copy.

You can also drop leading bytes. This would take 128 bytes starting after 10 bytes:

```
let toWrite = data.dropFirst(10).prefix(128)
```

Again, this is safe if `data` is too short, and is O(1) and does not copy any data.

You can also use subscripts in the way that EmilioPalaez describes, but you need to be very careful about non-0 `startIndex` (which is easy to forget), the syntax can get messy to do correctly, and it will crash if out of range. I generally recommend using collection methods rather than subscripts because of that.

Your question actually asks for an array of bytes, even though your sample code expects a Data. If you really do need `[UInt8]`, then the correct way to do that is with an array initializer over the Data slice.

```
let array: [UInt8] = Array(data.prefix(128))
```

This causes a single copy in O(n), but is otherwise like the other solutions.

Comment: This is very clear. Thank you. I'm doing a loop to send 128 bytes at a time so I would have to use the dropFirst. Let me try it this way. I do need to send an array of bytes. I might have to have a 2nd question on this one as I didn't want to have a multi-question post, but you are right.

Comment: You might find this talk useful, particularly from about 2:30 - 6:30 which covers Data slicing: https://vimeo.com/601943234

Answer (score 1):

The `Data` object has a `subscript` method that takes a `Range<Data.Index>`. Because of the way indices are handled*, you should get the indices values from the data object itself.

```
let startIndex = fileData.startIndex
let endIndex = startIndex.advanced(by: 128)
let subdata = fileData[startIndex..<endIndex]
let bytes = [UInt8](subdata)
```

*the `startIndex` of a `Data` object may not be 0 in some cases, for example, when using a "slice" of another `Data` object.

Comment: [`Data.Index`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/index) is just a typealias to `Int`. Are you sure `Int` doesn’t work?

Comment: @LeoDabus right, I improved the wording, but the reason to use the indices of the object is that in some situations, like after getting a Data "slice", the `startIndex` may not be 0.

Comment: This seems like the best answer since it handles cases like slices. (voted)

Comment: It would be helpful to mention the non-zero startIndex problem in the answer text. This is a common and surprising mistake and it's good that you protect against it.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez yes but fileData in the OP is `Data`  type not a slice. Btw be careful when using subscript. You should use `Data`’s  subdata method to avoid miss-alignment errors

Comment: @LeoDabus We don't know if its a slice or not, since it's passed in. Data is unusual in that it is its own slice type, and so you can't tell. Subscripts should not create any alignment errors since it reads byte-by-byte. The alignment problem happens when you try to use `load` on the pointer to read a multi-byte value like an Int16. Using `subdata` produces a copy, which does realign the memory, but also represents a non-trivial cost in many use cases and isn't generally necessary unless you later perform loads (in which case you should make the copying choice at that point, not earlier).